# What is the problem if my car's engine stops running in the middle of a ride?

Tags: engine, gasoline, winter

My car's engine frequently stops in the middle of a ride. Its an old model of Hyundai Sonata 2004. This happens especially in high gears(3,4) and faster speeds (like 60-70 mph). It has also happened in the lower gears 1,2.

Now, when this happens, I slide the car on the side road using emergency lights and halt it. When I am restarting my car, I have to push the brake and gas pedal till the end to get the car starting again. There is nothing wrong with the battery.

Comment: Are you saying that you need to press the brake to get it to start again?

Comment: Yes. @MaxGoodridge: That question is not a duplicate. My question is entirely different and with very different symptoms.

Comment: If you don't press the brake, does the starter motor turn?

Comment: Check engine light on?

Comment: Akshayrajkore- rather than edit the diagnosis into your question, please post it as an answer. As regards the range for repairing - that is off topic here: we can't provide shopping cost recommendations as they are so variable between cities, countries etc.

Answer (score 3):

If while trying to start the engine without pressing the brake, the engine turns over but does not start, then I would suspect a fault in the brake booster that is letting unmetered air into the vacuum circuit.  This would cause a very weak mixture while the throttle is closed during starting, which would cause the problem you are having.

When you press the brake and open the throttle, this air leak may stop or become insignificant compared to the air flowing through the normal metered air intake path, so allowing the engine to start.